# Is a Van de Graaff generator a voltage or current source?

Tags: voltage, current, circuit-analysis, basic

I'm currently studying basics of electrostatics and this question comes to me as any generator must be from either of the two types but which is the fact I'm not able to justify which. From its internal construction it does not simply fit in either of the two.

Comment: It moves electrons on a rubber belt. Moving charges does fit one of those types rather well.

Comment: Isn't that an internal phenomenon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A van den Graff generator is considered a current source because it is capable of providing the same current no matter the voltage that is developed. There is a constant transfer of charge

The fact the current capability is tiny doesn't change the fact it's behaviour is that of an almost ideal current source.

Answer (score 2):

The Van Der Graaf generator is a current source or constant current device. When connecting a load to the generator the voltage varies, but the current stays the same.

Comment: can you plz. elaborate your explanation for clear view.thanks

Comment: I had a nice picture of an equivalent circuit during my study, but I cannot find it anymore. As I remember it correctly it was a capacitor parallel to the source and a large resistor.

Comment: no problem thanks for help. by the way if you find it plz. post it would be great. thanks